# is there a standard PHP function for transfering an associative array elements to another associative array

Tags: php, arrays, function, indexing, associative-array

Is there a standard PHP function that changes an associative array's index names?

```
$a1 = array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
$new_index_names = array('one'=>'ono','two'=>'dos','three'=>'tres');

$a2 = change_index_names($a1,$new_index_names);

print_r($a2);

// $a2 should have the index names changed accordingly and look like this:  
//  array('ono'=>1,'dos'=>2,'tres'=>3)
```

**EDIT**
Please note that the function needs to know the mappings to the new index names.  Meaning, in $new_index_names array provides the mappings.  So again, it needs to know that 'ono' is the new index name for 'one'.

**EDIT**
I know you guys can come up with your own solution, i was wondering there is a standard PHP function that already does this.

**EDIT**

There are several situations where changing index names would help:
  1) separates post value names to generic/internal names so you can separate
     your backend code from front-end code.
  2) say for instance you have two arrays from post that need to go through the 
     same exact process, except both arrays although mean/contain same exact type 
     of values/order/structure, they're index names are different.  So when 
     passing to a function/method that goes by only a set of index names, you'll 
     need to convert the index names before passing them to that function/method.

Comment: Any reason you are looking for an internal function? `foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) $a2[$new_index_names[$k]] = $v;` is not that much code to write.

Comment: just wondering if there a standard php function instead rewriting code.

Comment: jh1711 - actually your's doesn't preserve order or mappings provided in $new_index_names.

Comment: the order from $a1 should be maintained. And the mappings provided by $new_index_names should be preserved. There's no treatment for keys that exist in $a1, but not in $new_index_names, which is something I would add in any 'real code'. If you prefer the order of $new_index_keys you can just loop over it instead of $a1.

Comment: jh1711 - your right the order is preserved.  u could add this anwer and ill check off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I've seen thus far:

```
foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) $a2[$new_index_names[$k]] = $v;
```

Credits go to jh1711

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `array_values` To get your desired output you can just use

`array_combine($new_index_names,$a1);`

Comment: Missed that part. +1

Comment: In the rare case that one of the arrays is not sorted by its index this could produce [wrong results](https://3v4l.org/A2LKR). Otherwise +1.

Comment: nice.  but only problem is $new_index_names array has to have elements in right order.  I also wanted ot preserve the mapping preserved in my $new_index_names so it knows from which index in $a1 to get the value from.

Comment: If sort order is an issue but both arrays have identical keys then you can `array_merge($a1, $new_index_names)`

Answer (score 2):

not in just 1 function, but you could use `array_values` to get the values of the first array, and `array_combine` to set the new keys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays has equal count, one way is with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$a2 = array_combine(array_values($new_index_names), $a1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers does not consider the order of `$a1` and `$new_index_names`, so I put my solution following:

```
$a1 = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'zero' => 0);
$new_index_names = array('zero' => 'zero', 'one' => 'ono', 'two' => 'dos', 'three' => 'tres');

array_combine(
    $new_index_names, 
    str_replace(array_keys($a1), array_values($a1), array_keys($new_index_names))
);

Array
(
    [zero] => 0
    [ono] => 1
    [dos] => 2
    [tres] => 3
)
```

Comment: there was a better solution.